# Interface Builder "Simulate Interface" not working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am using Interface Builder to play around with some ideas. I never noticed that there is a "Simulate Interface" feature which apparently will render the nib in the iPhone simulator. So, I created a view, put one component in there (a Segmented Control), saved it, selected "Simulate Interface", the simulator launched but... nothing rendered in the simulator. Just a black screen.

I thought maybe my nib wasn't complete enough, so I've tried it with all of my old nibs and I'm having the same problem with all of them. None of them render in the simulator at all. Is there some trick that I'm missing?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be relevant anymore as since  updating to 3.0 I haven't had the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen this anymore since 3.0 update

Answer (score 2):

I think this is essentially the same as doing "build and go" from xcode, your interface needs to be hooked up to a working application for it to "simulate"

Answer (score 1):

The UIView has to be contained within a UIWindow to be visible during Simulate Interface mode.

Buttons will show highlight and select behaviors, the Activity Indicator will even animate.

UITextField will even let you enter text but the keyboard will only be dismissed via Return key, not by touching outside the text area.

Picker views, date views and text views will have dummy values inside but you can scroll them.

UIImageViews / UIImages will not appear, even inside buttons or other controls.